# Spring Security Java Config - custom AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I use java configuration to configure Spring Security, and I have customized AuthenticationProvider and customized UserDetailsService, to add extra login field following 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/95715-extra-login-fields

I have difficulty to add both of the customized Classes into Spring Security framework by using java configuration.
As java doc of AuthenticationProvider#authenticationProvider describes:

> Add authentication based upon the custom AuthenticationProvider that
>   is passed in. Since the AuthenticationProvider implementation is
>   unknown, all customizations must be done externally and the
>   AuthenticationManagerBuilder is returned immediately.
>
> This method does NOT ensure that the UserDetailsService is available
>   for the getDefaultUserDetailsService() method.

So my question is what is the approach to set UserDetailsService in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of customized AuthenticationProvider and customized UserDetailsService:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider impl = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        impl.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService());
        /* other properties etc */
        return impl ;
    }

    @Bean   
    UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
        /* custom UserDetailsService code here */
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you initialize your `customAuthenticationProvider` and `customUserDetailsService` manually, is it not better to `@Autowired` them directly?

Comment: `@Autowired` is used in `@Configuration` class when you are wiring outside beans. In this code, `customAuthenticationProvider` and `customUserDetailsService` beans are declared in the same class and so there is no use case for `@Autowired`. Also note that `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` is declared somewhere else and so it is ok to use `@Autowired`.

Comment: impl.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService()); // this will not work, - the AuthenticationProvider interface has no setUserDetailsService() method.

Comment: Since it is a custom AuthenticationProvider implementation, you can add this method (after all any authentication provider would need a mechanism to load user details).  See implementations of `AuthenticationProvider` such as [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html), which has the `setUserDetailsService` method.