# How to inject my custom ProviderManager into AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application, I've come out my custom `MyProviderManager` where I'd like to control the logic inside method *`authenticate`*

```
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        // instead of iterating in the AuthenticationProvider list one by one
        // I'd rather choose the right AuthenticationProvider based on the currently requested URL path
        RequestDetails requestDetails = authentication.getDetails();
        if ("/ad/sso".equals(requestDetails.getPath())) {
            return adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } else if ("/saml/sso".equals(requestDetails.getPath())) {
            return samlAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } else if ("/oidc/sso".equals(requestDetails.getPath())) {
            return oidcAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } else  {
            return ldapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, I'm now having it hard to inject my custom `MyProviderManager` with *AuthenticationManagerBuilder* so that the method *`performBuild`*() in *AuthenticationManagerBuilder* will return `MyProviderManager` instead of the default one from Spring Security

I had even tried to come out my custom `MyAuthenticationManagerBuilder` exends `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and overridden *`performBuild`()* method, but I faced the same issue of how to inject my custom AuthenticationManagerBuilder to Spring Boot

It is really appreciate if someone could shed the light on the issues here or have better alternative ideas tackling my special requirements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security Java Config - custom AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276152/spring-security-java-config-custom-authenticationprovider-and-userdetailsservi)

Comment: all AuthentictionProviders including custom AuthenticationProvider are iterated by ProviderManager. I'd like to have a custom ProviderManager where I could have better control which AuthenticationProvider will be used for which URL paths

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom AuthenticationManager implementation, you do not use an AuthenticationManagerBuilder anymore (that is what would build an AuthenticationManager but you already have one). Instead expose AuthenticationManager as a bean and do not use AuthenticationManagerBuilder.

```
@Bean
CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Comment: Does it indicate that I should **NOT** override 
`protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`
 and  
`protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`
 in the MySecurityConfig that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

On the contrary `CustomAuthenticationManager` should by itself instantiate all necessary `AuthenticationProvider` list, right?